# Specify which analyses to perform in Ghidra headless mode

Tags: ghidra

Basically, Ghidra in headless mode is divided into three phases: preScript, analysis, and postScript.

Pre/post scripts are written extending the [GhidraScript](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/app/script/GhidraScript.html) class, while analysis ones extend the [AbstractAnalyzer](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/app/services/AbstractAnalyzer.html) class.

When you run Ghidra in headless mode, you can specify which pre/post scripts you want to run (`-preScript` and `-postScript` options).

My questions is: how do I choose which analyses to perform?

For example, if I run this command:

```
./analyzeHeadless /tmp test -import ~/Downloads/test.elf -scriptPath ~/ghidra_scripts/ -postScript TestScript.java
[...]

INFO  -----------------------------------------------------
    ARM Constant Reference Analyzer           14.667 secs
[...]
    Subroutine References - One Time           0.000 secs
-----------------------------------------------------
     Total Time   86 secs
-----------------------------------------------------
 (AutoAnalysisManager)
```

How can I exclude the `ARM Constant Reference Analyzer` and add another analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. You can select desired analysis options in the `prescript`. Checkout this function - [setAnalysisOption](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/app/script/GhidraScript.html#setAnalysisOption(ghidra.program.model.listing.Program,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) in `GhidraScript` class. You can also look @ this [example](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/2b08598dbabe6a9c911e712bd928e5f84fb00ee8/Ghidra/Features/Base/ghidra_scripts/TurnOffStackAnalysis.java) script.

So, in your case you can do something like:

```
from ghidra.app.script import GhidraScript
setAnalysisOption(currentProgram, "ARM Constant Reference Analyzer", "false")
```

Comment: It works! Thanks.
For the readers:
if you want to enable some analysis that ends with the `(Prototype)` string, e.g.,  `Aggressive Instruction Finder (Prototype)`, just use `Aggressive Instruction Finder`.